# DNS broken after upgrade to Bionic Beaver

Tags: dns, dnsmasq, ubuntu-18.04

I just upgraded my Ubuntu box to Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic Beaver), and my DNS stopped working. The one "funny" thing about this box is that I want it to run `dnsmasq` instead of `systemd-resolved`, because I'm running Pi-Hole on this box.  I've tried a bunch of things, the important things (I think) are currently:

`/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` contains `dns=dnsmasq` in the `[main]` section.

I've disabled `systemd-resolved`:

```
sudo systemctl disable systemd-resolved.service
sudo service systemd-resolved stop
```

Pi-hole does seem to be running:

```
chris@psi:/etc/systemd$ sudo pihole status
  [✓] DNS service is running
  [✓] Pi-hole blocking is Enabled
```

`/etc/resolv.conf` is a symlink

```
chris@psi:~$ ls -l /etc/resolv.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 27 Jun 10 14:55 /etc/resolv.conf -> /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
```

and contains:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

Yet any attempt to do a DNS lookup fails:

```
chris@psi:~$ host pi-hole.net
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

One other odd thing. I get hit the Pi-Hole admin website, but it says that I only have 1 domain on the blocklist (and that was about 125K this morning, before I mucked things up).

I'm really thrashing right now – I can't seem to find any good DNS diagnostic tools (**please tell me what DNS servers you are trying, and where you're looking for DNS server**) or any log files that will give me a hint of what is going on.

Any clues for the clueless?